# Completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ other than $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

As an example of topological space, is there a completion of $\mathbb{Q}$, other than $\mathbb{R}$ and p-adic number $\mathbb{Q}_p$, in use?

In other words, is there other kind of metric defined on $\mathbb{Q}$ with some interesting properties?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is a pretty horrible topological space and you can do all sorts or horrible things with it. For example, split it into disjoint parts $(-\infty, \sqrt{2}) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ and $(\sqrt{2}, \infty) \cap \mathbb{Q}$, and complete the two pieces in different ways.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski%27s_theorem

Comment: There are three different absolute values that can be put on $\mathbb{Q}$ then completed to give intrinsically different spaces:  the usual absolute value (which completes to $\mathbb{R}$, a $p$-adic absolute value (which completes to $\mathbb{Q}_p$, or the trivial absolute value (which makes $\mathbb{Q}$ into a complete, totally disconnected metric space).  This is essentially the substance of Ostrowski's theorem.  That said, if you don't require your metric to come from an absolute value, you can do almost anything.

Comment: The completion is not as a *topological* space. There is no notion of a "complete topological space". You need more structure to talk about completeness, so you can talk about uniform spaces, etc. In this particular case you mean ***metric space***.

Comment: @Hurkyl I've never seen that before. That's really *really* gross.

Comment: @XanderHenderson why do we only ever look at completions that come from absolute values? For example Wikipedia says an adele ring is the “restricted product of all the completions of the global field”, implicitly completely disregarding completions that don’t come from absolute values. Even if we want to only consider completions that are fields, completions w.r.t. submultiplicative “absolute values” also result in fields, I think?